# Join two context tables in one collection

Tags: c#

I have a two different database contexts - FruitsDBContext and SuppliersDBContext. they both come from different servers.

```
 DBContext1 ->   FruitsDBContext{int fruitid,
                                 string name,
                                 int supplierServiceId}

 DBContext2 -> SupplierDBContext {int supplierid,
                                  string suppliername,
                                  datetime suppliedDte} 

  Result Class -> Fruit{ int fruitid,
                     string name,
                     int supplierServiceId,
                     int supplierid,
                     string suppliername,
                     datetime suppliedDte}
```

how do I construct a result set of a Fruit Class collection from two differnt context the join by 'supplierServiceId' field)

I want to get a list of different fruits imported from different supplier grouped by day

Comment: Why don't you build a `Fruit` class with all the instances you want and just put a new entry to a list of that class each time you receive a new fruit with all its context and suppliercontext informations?

Comment: the question is - how to query two different database contexts tables and perform a join- and  put the result in a collection... using linq

Comment: You'll have to store the data from the both contexts into a class to make it easier reachable.